# Any drawbacks to having very descriptive table and column names in DB tables for Java web app?

Tags: database-design, jpa

I would like to know if there are any drawbacks to having descriptive names for database tables and columns. This would be for a Java based web application, and most of the times I have seen database tables or columns, they have had abbreviations for the tables and columns, such as "CD" when referring to "Code". Would there be any performance issues if the names of tables and columns are a bit fuller to increase readability of the Java classes that would get generated by JPA, even if it means reaching the upper limit for the allowed lengths for table and column names? There would be hundreds of tables in this application (enterprise app).

Thank you.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5588/87245

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find a balance.

`AnIncrediblyLongVariableOrTableName` is almost as hard to deal with as `TooShrt` - especially when you're looking at a block of code (or a sproc) that mentions a half dozen of them within 20 lines.

If the names are too long, you'll see a significant performance hit - in your developer's brains.  It will be harder to read the code, harder to fix it, harder to enhance it, etc.  Hard to read code can add hours or days to the development cycle.

From a computer performance point of view, I'd be astonished if you could measure a significant difference between hyper short names and ridiculously long names.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, finding a balance. But are there any quantitative drawbacks that could be meaningful or would it be a negligible performance impact as the names get longer?

Comment: Probably not.  I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

There's a limt on how long column names can be in mosd DBMSes: Postgres and MySQL allow 64 characters, Oracle only 30.

It's fine when you have a long name for something primary, but once you start considering related tables, you might need to combine FK column names to show their relationship. For instance, if you have an `worldwide_catalog_id` column on an `agriculture_product` table, and add it as an FK to a `recurring_customer` table as a favorite, you might end up referring to it as `recurring_customer.favorite_product_wordwide_catalog_id`. It may be acceptable from the readability POV, but you may end up hitting DBMS limits.

Use column comments to precisely explain the purpose of a specific column.

Try being pragmatic introducing shorter column names. Maintain a thesaurus for that, a list of uniform common abbreviations, etc, so that new developers have easier time picking it up, and you yourself don't forget.